# Python Turtles Colour filling

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

This might be a problem with my triangle, maybe the edges don't connect properly, but my triangle isn't filling how I want it to:

```
#Draw
bob.pen(fillcolor="#b11874")
bob.pensize(3)
#Sierpinski 1
bob.begin_fill()
bob.forward(150)
bob.left(120)
bob.forward(150)
bob.left(120)
bob.forward(150)
bob.end_fill()
#colouring2
bob.pen(fillcolor="#ff6600")
bob.begin_fill()
bob.left(180)
bob.forward(75)
bob.right(60)
bob.forward(75)
bob.right(120)
bob.end_fill()
```

The first fill works fine and colours the triangle purple, but when I start the 2nd fill, it cuts the triangle in half.

I'm drawing Sierpinskis and trying to colour exterior triangles one colour and interior triangles another. This is the whole code:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BaPrU0N4AaVL9w4zp9WIe-c4LOFp9EPO/view?usp=sharing if you want to test it out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show how you *want* your triangle to be colored so it's hard to pinpoint the correct answer.  Basically, if you don't fill a *closed* polygon, which you didn't the second time, then turtle will connect the first and last point for you before filling it.  So if we want the bottom filled with a different color we could do:

```
import turtle         
bob = turtle.Turtle()
window = turtle.Screen()

# Draw
bob.pen(fillcolor="purple")
bob.pensize(3)

# Sierpinski 1
bob.begin_fill()
bob.forward(150)
bob.left(120)
bob.forward(150)
bob.left(120)
bob.forward(150)
bob.end_fill()

# colouring 2
bob.pen(fillcolor="orange")
bob.begin_fill()
bob.left(180)
bob.forward(75)
bob.right(60)
bob.forward(75)
bob.right(60)
bob.forward(75)
bob.end_fill()

window.exitonclick()
```

I didn't close the polygon here either, I just let turtle connect the endpoints.

[image]

Comment: https://imgur.com/Sh2tL6M This is actually the colour design I wanted so that all the black lines would still be visible @cdlane